# Android Dynamically adding ImageView

Tags: android

I am Having a table layout in that i am adding table rows dynamically.in that table row i am adding two image views and one text view.how to fix the size of the image displayed in the image view.Please any one can suggest the answer.

If this way is not suitable one for acheiving this task ,Please suggest another ways

Comment: Have you tried using ImageScaleType?

Answer (score 0):

Check out `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(src, dstWidth, dstHeight, filter)` to scale the image.

Consider these functions as well; `ImageView.setPadding(0,0,0,0)` and `ImageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE)` to make it fit nice in your table.